# Object.equals for two VTDNav instances and cost of VTDNav.cloneNav

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

I am trying to implement a simple wrapper for vtd-xml. As this wrapper will allow for random access I have chosen to use VTDNav.cloneNav to allow the wrapper to simultaneously hold and traverse cursors to different parts of the XML. My questions are :

1. I am aware that cloning VTDNav instances will have a performance penalty but generally, how much are we talking about here? I will probably do some benchmarking once I am finished with the wrapper but perhaps some info on the cost could make me change some design decisions (maybe use only one VTDNav and clone only on request).
2. How can I compare two cloned instances of VTDNav and see if they point to the same node? I have noticed that the BookMark class has an equals and deepEquals method but I don't want to introduce more classes, more object instances and more references if not needed. Can I simply compare the current indexes of both instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answers below:

1. In general, clone() carries the overhead of allocating and copying an int array of about **30~40** integers in size in the most typical use cases... so unless the document you are working with is extremely small, it should not be a big deal...
2. Yes, compare current index works!!!

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented an initial version with AutoPilot reusage and the performance results are amazing! Almost to the point that I don't believe that it can possibly function correctly at such speed and memory usage :) I must say that I am puzzled as to why this library isn't more used and more well-known. Good luck with the future adoption, this is really great stuff!

Comment: I have seen it but I don't yet have a need for it. Generally, I have seen [this blog post](https://ximpleware.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/performance-tuning/) and will try to take these recommendations into consideration while keeping the wrapper library general-purpose.